# About non-uniquely determined simple function question

Tags: real-analysis

> Show the integral of $\phi \in S$ is well-defined by $\int_{[a,b]} \phi=\sum_{j=1}^k c_j \mu(A_j)$, where $\mu$ is Lebesgue measure and S is the collection of $\phi$ in which the sets $A_1,...,A_k$ (measurable sets) are not uniquely determined.
>
> Show $\int_{[a,b]} \phi=\sum_{j=1}^k c_j \mu(A_j)$ whenever $\phi(x)=\sum_{j=1}^k c_j \chi_{A_j}(x)$ for $x \in [a,b]$ and measurable sets $\{A_n\}$ are not assumed to be disjoint.

Definition of simple functions: Suppose we have a measurable space $(X,\mathcal{M})$. A simple function is a function on X which assumes only finitely many values in $[0,\infty)$, each one on a measurable set. A simple function may always be represented as $\sum_{k=1}^n \alpha_k \chi_{A_k}$, with pairwise distinct values $\alpha_k$ and pairwise distinct values $\alpha_k$ and pairwise disjoint non-empty measurable sets $A_k$ whose union is X. This representation, being uniquely determine, is called the canonical representation of the function.

I am not sure how those two questions work under non-uniquely determined and non-disjoint cases. I always thought sigma additivity assumes on disjoint measurable sets. Need more observations to see the question, thanks in advance.

Comment: This is super classical. Maybe this helps: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1947044/prove-lesbesgue-integration-definition-for-simple-function-is-well-defined

Comment: @fcz thanks, let me take a look